# MultipleCompilationErrorsException is showing when I add two code in pre-processor

Tags: jmeter

I wrote below given code in Jmeter pre-processor
${__fifoPop(sync_tokensa, gotTokena_1)}
${__fifoPop(sync_tokensaq, gotTokena_2)}

error showing as
Response code:500
Response message:javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script394.groovy: 1: unexpected token:  @ line 1, column 38.
    U0pDVVdtaUJRa0xQSEVodzE1MDEyNTM2MzQ=

Answer (score 0):

As per [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) documentation:

> When using this feature, ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables directly in script code as caching would only cache first replacement. Instead use script parameters.

Don't inline [JMeter Functions and/or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into the Groovy scripts, it may cause either compilation failure or incorrect interpretation or only first value will be used or any combination of all above.

Go for code-based equivalent like:

```
1.upto(2, { number ->
    vars.put('gotTokena_' + number, kg.apc.jmeter.modifiers.FifoMap.getInstance().pop('sync_tokensaq'))
})
```

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)